# Debugging Maven in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea

I recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA (Community edition) and the switch went great. Anyway, I'm facing only one issue.

For my work I have to work with Maven, which I don't really mind, for dependency management. No problem, but debugging seems to be way different on IntelliJ than on Eclipse. For instance in Eclipse I can just click debug 'project' and set breakpoints and such, which when they are reached stop the application and start my debugger.

However on IntelliJ I have to debug start my application from the Maven Lifecycle window and than attach a debugger from the regular run configurations. Which in general is driving me a little crazy, it's just a tedious job.

So my question is, is there a better, more efficient way of debugging Maven applications in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: What kind of application do you have? (how do you run it normally?)

Comment: Try debugging via Maven Helper plugin http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea_ce